# C# what is the regex expression for Special characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, expression

What is the regex expression for the special characters that is greater than 128 in the ASCII extended table?

I have a line with special characters like below, and every special char should be replaced with a space.

```
input --->  "H€ELLOŠŠŠŠWorld$"
output -->  "H ELLO    World$"
```

N.B.: $ is special character that has ASCII<128

To know ASCII<128 characters
http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: i'm a beginner to regex

Comment: I think you need to define "special" here. What is special about those characters?

Comment: Why do you need a **regular expression**?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen .. look at this table http://www.ascii-code.com/
i need all characters that is < 128
and all characters > 128 replaced with space

Comment: Are you saying that *all* characters with a code point from 128 and up should be replaced? Or are there "non-special" characters above 128 you want to keep?

Comment: all chars > 128 should be replaced with space

Comment: So `[\u0080-\uffff]` ?

Comment: In the future, please keep your question simple. "Special characters that is greater than 128" implies that not *all* the characters above are interesting, only the *special* ones, but no such definition was provided. So the question was unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following:

```
var re = new Regex(@"[\u0080-\uFFFF]");

var s = re.Replace("H€ELLOŠŠŠŠWorld. This is a sample 1234 $.", " ");

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
H ELLO    World. This is a sample 1234 $.
```

---

[**IDEONE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/vHat0R)

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with regexes for this task?

```
var str = "H€ELLOŠŠŠŠWorld$";

var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
foreach(var c in str)
    sb.Append(c <= 128 ? c : ' ');

var result = sb.ToString();
```